# Check my reasoning - Any line as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a discrete topology

Tags: general-topology

I want to say that any line $L$ is a discrete topology when you consider the topology it inherents as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. My reasoning is that if you take a point on this line, and take the complement, you get the finite union of two lines. Lines are closed on $\mathbb{R}^2$. So the union of these two lines are closed in $L$ as it is equal to L intersected with a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But then that makes the complement of these two lines, the point set, is open. This is true for all point sets and therefore all point sets are open in $L$ and $L$ has the discrete topology.

Comment: A ray (you called *line*) in the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2$ is neither open nor closed. The point that you're looking at the complement of is a limit point of the ray on either side, but not in the open ray; hence, the ray is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

It is one of those situations when you have to think twice about statements you believe are true:

> Lines are closed on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

No, not lines in the sense you use here. Most certainly $\{(x,0)\ |\ x>0\}$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, because $(0,0)$ is its limit point outside of it. And it is a piece of X axis as you propose in your question. In fact your construction **never** produces closed "lines", because the point you remove is a limit point of both pieces.

Lines as in affine subspaces of dimension $1$ (or in other words subsets that can be described by some $ax+by=c$ equation) indeed are closed, but that's not how you use the word "line" here.